# Average's not working in python

Tags: python-3.x

So i can't figure out why the averageEven and  averageOdd, doesn't work. Any help would be great. This will only work if there all even. So 2222222 will give me 100% even but 4514324 will be 0% even and 0% odd. Its really weird.

```
valid = int(0)
odd = int(0)
even = int(0)


while (valid != 1):
    number = input('Enter a number(between 6-9 digits long): ')
    if (len(number) > 5 and len(number) < 10):
       valid = 1
    else:
        print('invalid input.')
for i in range(len(number)):
    currentNum = int(number[i])
    if(currentNum%2==0):
        print(str(currentNum) +' is even')
        even = even +  1
    else:
        print(str(currentNum) +' is odd')
        odd = odd + 1

averageEven = float((even//len(number))*100)
averageOdd = float((odd//len(number))*100)

print ('Percent of even numbers is: ' + str(averageEven) + '%')
print ('Percent of odd numbers is: ' + str(averageOdd) + '%')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you're getting the floored quotient. Instead of `//` you should be using `/`.

To elaborate, the floor of a number is the number rounded down to the nearest whole number. In the case of decimals less than 1, that's just 0. The floor of 1.0 is just 1. I'd bet that your code can also detect if a number is 100% odd.